# Common Lisp Error: Undeclared Free Variables

Tags: error-handling, lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that I'm trying to compile, but I've been pulling my hair out for the last 30 minutes trying to figure out why this code is giving me a `Undeclared free variable` error. I'm using Emacs, and cannot decipher why I'm getting this error.

```lisp
(defun pretty-all(res diff)
  (let* ((v-list (blank-unit-list res))
         (c-list (blank-unit-list res)))
    (complete-fill c-list v-list res (total-res res) diff)
    (format t
            "Resistance is ~S~% Voltage is ~S~% Current is ~S~%"
            res v-list c-list)))
```

`blank-unit-list` , `complete-fill` , `total-res` are all my custom-defined functions.

I'm pretty sure this error is related to how I structured my code, but as I've said before, I can't figure out what.

---

Copied from Emacs:

```
3 compiler notes:

CircuitFunctions.lisp:61:64:
  warning: Undeclared free variable RES

CircuitFunctions.lisp:61:70:
  warning: Undeclared free variable V-LIST

CircuitFunctions.lisp:61:81:
  warning: Undeclared free variable C-LIST

Compilation failed.
```

Comment: show us the exact error?

Comment: If I put empty definitions for `complete-fill`, `blank-unit-list`, and `total-res` in a file and add the above code for `pretty-all`, I can byte-compile it without any errors.

Comment: That's really weird.....

Comment: Which platform and version of Emacs are you using? Also: if those warnings are showing line:column numbers, I can't see how they could match up to the function you have shown.

Comment: I've compiled `complete-fill` and the method works, but this method can't. I actually using lispbox and believe I am using common lisp.

Comment: Edited question to remove elisp references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following wvxvw's suggestion that my code might have a missing parens somewhere, I scrolled through my file with `C-M-f`. It passed through without a problem and by now I was starting to give up. Lastly, just to make sure, I copied the code from this question and replaced my previous function with the one here. Somehow it works now. I don't know what it was that caused the problem, but it functions correctly now. Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SLIME (and it looks as if you may be, as you're using lispbox), there should be a way of going from a compiler note to where in the source it occurred. I don't remember the exact key combination (I could probably press it if you put an emacs with slime in front of me, but that doesn't mean I consciously remember what it is, unfortunately). Checking what key slime-next-error is bound to would probably be helpful and there may be something in the SLIME menu).

From looking at the line numbers in the compiler notes (I think the :61:64 and the like is source line and column), the actual emitted errors are not matching up (at all) to the code you have pasted. There is no line I can see that have all of `v-list`, `res` and `c-list` in that order. That might be due to a macro expansion, though (as a side note, it looks as if `complete-fill` either is a macro or destructively modifies two of its arguments).

Comment: Actually, I changed the order to test the error, and I forgot to alter the code accordingly. The order of the variables, then have little to do with the error. For clarity's sake, I edited the question to reflect congruity.